# Looking for literature on hand-head movement coordination (not hand-eye)

Tags: muscles, movement

sports scientists and kinesiologists, I'm a linguist working on sign languages and I'm looking for papers that discuss motor coordination of hand and head movements and potential constraints on such parallel movements (not hand-eye coordination, there's plenty of papers out there on that topic). In particular, I care about combinations of a repeated headshake and small, repeated twisting movements of wrist, as they occur in this sign in German Sign Language: https://www.sign-lang.uni-hamburg.de/.../type18133_de.html. Or head nods combined with a 'no' side-to side gesture of the dominant hand. Does anybody have clues as to why such movements might be difficult to combine? I'd be so grateful for any pointers!

Comment: consider also SE Medical Sciences, https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/, and maybe also fitness https://fitness.stackexchange.com/. If you do cross-post, make sure that you link each question to each other post to make it clear that you've posted in multiple places.

Comment: @MaximilianPress The guidance on cross-posting is that unless each post can be specifically tailored for the target site such that they aren't quite the same question anymore, the poster should choose one site for their question to live on, rather than posting in multiple places. It's fine to delete a question on one site to post it on another if OP changes their mind about the most appropriate venue.